# Is there a way to make custom Emmet abbreviations that input variables before expanding?

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

So, I'm using Emmet on Sublime Text 3, and I've already figured out how to do custom snippets (direct replacement without preprocessing when doing the expand abbreviation command),

```
"jq": "<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' integrity='sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=' crossorigin='anonymous' ></script>${child}"
```

and how to do custom abbreviations

```
"sym": "svg[width=${1} height=${1}]>symbol[ id='${2}' viewBox='0 0 ${1} ${1}']"
```

expands to

```
<svg width="|" height="|">
    <symbol id="" viewBox="0 0 | |"></symbol>
</svg>
```

What I want to know, is if there's a way to make a custom abbreviation such that it'll input some variables into the abbreviation like so

```
sym:w200h100x0y0#myCustomSymbol
```

expands to

```
<svg width="200" height="100">
    <symbol id="myCustomSymbol" viewBox="0 0 200 100">|</symbol>
</svg>
```

I thought it might be possible since we can do things link w100 in CSS expands to width:100px.

...as an aside to anyone who stumbles across this post trying to understand how to make their own customizations, you go to Preferences>Package Settings>Emmet>Settings - User
this opens up the file where you write a json of your custom stuff.
Preferences>Package Settings>Emmet>Settings - Default shows how it should be formatted.

```
{
    "variables": {
        "lang": "en",
        "greet":"Greetings and Salutations from the People of Earth"
    },
    "snippets": {
        "css": {
            "abbreviations": {
                "tsh": "text-shadow:${1:hoff} ${2:voff} ${3:blur} ${4:#000};"
            },
        },
        "html": {
            "snippets": {
                "jq": "<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' integrity='sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=' crossorigin='anonymous' />${child}",
                "hi":"<div>\n\t${greet}\n</div>"
            },
            "abbreviations": {
                "sym": "svg[width=${1} height=${1}]>symbol[ id='${2}' viewBox='0 0 ${1} ${1}']",
                "hello":"h1>{${greet}}>span"
                // variables can't be placed at the end of an abbreviation, for some reason.
                // however h1>{${greet}} expands correctly if explicit typed in the html document.
            }
        }
    },
    "preferences": {
        "css.valueSeparator": ": ",
        "css.propertyEnd": ";"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there’s no such option in Emmet. It assumes that you should expand abbreviation first, then fill-in fields by tabbing through them